# How can I reach an element in an Object?

Tags: php, oop

I'm trying to reach an element in an object array. But I couldn't succeed. 
Let's think this as an object called $result
How can I reach maskedNumber?

```
Braintree_Result_Successful Object
(
    [success] => 1
    [_returnObjectName:private] => customer
    [customer] => Braintree_Customer Object
        (
            [_attributes:protected] => Array
                (
                    [creditCards] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Braintree_CreditCard Object
                                (
                                    [_attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [maskedNumber] => ***********5897
```

Comment: I asked to braintree and it seems I can retrieve after credit card creation. Now problem solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by asking braintreepayments. They said that I could retrieve this data after I add user to braintree. But my solution is if I really needed this at the very beginning would be to take it with REGEX. For people who are looking for a great online payment company I suggest you to go with braintree

Answer (score 2):

Since the `_attributes` property of `Braintree_Customer` is protected you will need to define an accessor method.  The other `_attributes` property of `Braintree_CreditCard` also looks like it's supposed to be protected, so I've assumed an identical accessor should exist:

```
$cards = $object->customer->getAttribute('creditCards');
$number = $cards[0]->getAttribute('maskedNumber');
```

Accessor method to be placed in both classes:

```
function getAttribute($attribute) {
    return $this->_attributes[$attribute];
}
```

**Edit:**

Just to improve upon my original answer a little, I would put some decent error checking in an actual accessor method.

```
function getAttribute($attribute) {
    if (isset($this->_attributes[$attribute])) {
      return $this->_attributes[$attribute];
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

You could also consider using the [magic methods](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php) `__get()` and `__set()` to act as getters and setters.

Comment: Your explaination is great but I got this error . Probably a little bit edit will solve the problem.
Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttribute() on a non-object in

Comment: @SNaRe I would first check the $object variable (call `var_dump()` or `get_class()`.  Then the customer property.  Or, if the error is concerning my second line of code, repeat the procedure for $cards[0]. :)

Comment: Now I fixed something and I have different error 
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Braintree_Customer::getAttribute()

Comment: @SNaRe In that case, you haven't put the getAttribute() method in your class definition.  Copy and paste it into your Braintree_Customer class.  Alternatively, if it is going to be a method common to several classes then you should put it in a common parent class instead.

Comment: Actually I don't know how to do. What I have is an object. It seems I will do this with regex :)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but this might help some.

Braintree has methods for returning the protected information that's returned from functions like Braintree_Customer::create();

```
$result = Braintree_Customer::create(array(
    'firstName'     => $_POST['first_name'],
    'lastName'      => $_POST['last_name'],
    'email'         => $_POST['email'],
    'creditCard'    => array(
        'cardholderName'    => $_POST['cardholder_name'],
        'number'            => $_POST['number'],
        'expirationMonth'   => $_POST['month'],
        'expirationYear'    => $_POST['year'],
        'cvv'               => $_POST['cvv'],
        'billingAddress'    => array(
            'postalCode'        => $_POST['postal_code']
        )
    )
));

var_dump($result->customer->__get('id'));
var_dump($result->customer->__get('creditCards'));
```

The _attributes of customer are protected, but the get function returns them.
This method does not require re-requesting data from Braintree.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$Result->customer->_attributes['creditCards'][0]->_attributes['maskedNumber']
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined property on Braintree_Customer: _attributes in

Answer (score 0):

with `$result->customer` you should get the *Braintree_Customer* Object and then in that object you should have methods to retrieve the cards as those methods are protected and cannot be accessed directly. Something like

```
$customer = $result->customer;
foreach($customer->getCreditCards() as $card)
{
   echo $card->getMaskedNumber(); // You will need to create that method too
}
```

Example of getCreditCards method:

```
Class Braintree_Customer
{
  protected $creditCards;

  function getCreditCards()
  {
     return $creditCards;
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: What kind of method should I create?

Comment: getCreditCards() and getMaskerNumber(), so you can access those protected attributes.. if you show us how is declare each of those classes we can help more..

Comment: Actually I'm not good at OOP. Things that you wrote probably right but I don't know how to apply. I have just an object with contents. Thanks anyway

Comment: @SNaRe sorry I can't help you more.. do you have access to the source code of those clases so we can see them?

Comment: Yes. this is their website. All source codes are open. http://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/php/